# Ember Simple Auth (with token plugin) won't add the Authorization header with the token

Tags: ember.js, http-headers, token, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I had a simple and working application with Ember CLI 0.1.12. I use the Ember Simple Auth addon with the Token authenticator and authorizer. https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token

First, I wasn't able to authenticate, because I had no idea what the server was supposed to return. After a lot of googling, I was able to figure out that the server should return something like this:

{ "access_token": "ToKeN123hEre" }

Now I was able to authenticate and sessions work. But when I make other calls, the Authorization header doesn't appear in the request headers, so it's impossible for the server to know the token.

**This is what I have tried so far:**

Setting my environment.js file:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  crossOriginWhitelist: ['*'],
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token',
  routeAfterAuthentication: '/profile'
};

ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
  serverTokenEndpoint: '/api0/auth',
  identificationField: 'username',
  passwordField: 'password',
  tokenPropertyName: 'token',
  authorizationPrefix: 'Bearer ',
  authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization',
  headers: {}
};
```

Make my server use CORS and allow the Authentication header and requests from any Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing "access_token" for simply "token", and now it works.

Comment: This is a new change that just came to ember-simple-auth, because of how Rails uses the authenticate_with_http_token  method. See issue here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/387