# Ember simple auth sending token for every request

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using ember-simple-auth with ember-simple-auth-token for authentication API, and I'm having the same issue as [Ember Simple Auth (with token plugin) won't add the Authorization header with the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353478/ember-simple-auth-with-token-plugin-wont-add-the-authorization-header-with-th), but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

The server is clearly responding with the token, but subsequent requests don't have the token in the header. GET requests should have the token in the header, right?

These are my options:

```
 ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token',
    authenticationRoute: 'login',
    routeAfterAuthentication: '/'
  };

  ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
    identificationField: 'email',
    serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/users/compare',
    tokenPropertyName: 'token',
    authorizationPrefix: 'Bearer ',
    authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization',
    headers: {}
  };
```

Comment: Are you able to console log out what your session object looks like when you have been authorized?